# CSS Moving picture by button click slightly to left and right?

Tags: css

Guys i have a picture that i want to move, after this button click:

```
<button class="ggEHit" (click)="Hit(chosenHero, actualEnemy);removeWholeBlock();">Hit! ({{heroMinHitAt}}
            -{{heroMaxHitAt - 1}})
       </button>
```

It calls this Method, which calls the method that should toggle my picture:

```
Hit(x: Hero, enemy: Enemy): void {
    this.moveFist();
    const zufall: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.heroMaxHitAt - this.heroMinHitAt)) + this.heroMinHitAt;
    const zufall2: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    this.hideWinHero();
...


moveFist(): void {

    document.getElementById('Puke').classList.toggle('enemyPic');



  }
```

Now my css:

```
.enemyPic{
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes example {
0%    {left:100px; top:100px;}
10%   {right:100px; top:200px;}
20%   {left:100px; top:100px;}
30%   {right:100px; top:200px;}
40%   {left:100px; top:100px;}
50%   {right:100px; top:200px;}
60%   {left:100px; top:100px;}
70%   {right:100px; top:200px;}
80%   {left:100px; top:100px;}
90%   {right:100px; top:200px;}
100%  {right:100px; top:200px;}
}

<div class="col text-center" *ngIf="actualEnemy.name === 'Pukepuke'">
        <img id="Puke" class="enemyPic" src="../../assets/Images/Puke.jpg" height="223" width="250"/>
      </div>
```

What did i miss, that my picture doesnt move on button click?

Comment: I don't see you calling the `moveFist()` function anywhere.

Comment: gegenEnemy(x: Hero, enemy: Enemy): void { // WEITERLEITEN AUF NEUE SEITE, NEUES KAMPFSYSTEM ALS EXTRA
    this.moveFist();


watch the gegenEnemy function

Comment: I see that. But it looks like when you click the button you are calling the `Hit()` and `removeWholeBlock()` functions. Not `gegenEnemy()`.

Comment: Im sry i just edited it correctly, i was just changing the names to not have so much foreign language in it and forgot this one

Comment: Also I'm not sure if you need do add `this.` before calling `moveFist()`.

Comment: I do need it. I tried to call the function in the HTML too, doesnt work